# jQuery slideToggle not working on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery slideToggle problem in IE8 only using lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902478/jquery-slidetoggle-problem-in-ie8-only-using-lists)

I have a code that slideToggles the contents of list items. It works fine in FF but in IE8 when clicking the item, instead of slide show the content, it always shows the content and slides up to hide it.
Here is the code of the list:

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li>
        <h4 class="head">Title 1</h4>
        <p>Content 1.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4 class="head">Title 2</h4>
        <p>Content 2.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the JS/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(250);
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
```

And here is the online page: http://grupoautolider.com.ar/galeria/cabriolet

This is strange because this code is featured in jQuery UI's doc page. It must be noted that this doesn't happen in IE7. I would be very grateful for your answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I may be wrong, but you shouldn't need to hide if you're using slidetoggle(). The toggle will automatically hide.

Comment: Hi Grillz, thanks for your comment, the hide() method is for initial hiding of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the problem as mentioned here : [slideToggle causes margin to disappear in IE8](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ie8-bug-slidetoggle-disappearing-margins-example-included)

just giving overflow:hidden to the divs where margin is disappearing would solve it. please check..